# C program to calculate the determinant of a NxN matrix

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a program that would calculate the determinant for me, and this is what I've done so far. But it's not working it just prints 6356918 for every matrix I throw at it. I've even compared my code to some other codes on the internet but that didn't work.

And I don't know anything about pointers so I cannot use them. I tried debugging which I don't know much about it either, but there seems to be something wrong with the first 'if' in the second function and the last part of the code which calculates the determinant. I'm coding in code::blocks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
    int A[100][100];
    int i,j,k,n,res;
    printf("Enter the order of the matrix: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the elements of the matrix one by one: \n");
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d",A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    res = det(A,n);
    printf("%d",res);
}
int det(int A[100][100], int n)
{
    int Minor[100][100];
    int i,j,k,c1,c2;
    int determinant;
    int c[100];
    int O=1;

    if(n == 2)
    {
        determinant = 0;
        determinant = A[0][0]*A[1][1]-A[0][1]*A[1][0];
        return determinant;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
            for(j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
            {
                for(k = 0 ; k < n ; k++)
                {
                    if(j != 0 && k != i)
                    {
                        Minor[c1][c2] = A[j][k];
                        c2++;
                        if(c2>n-2)
                        {
                            c1++;
                            c2=0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            determinant = determinant + O*(A[0][i]*det(Minor,n-1));
            O=-1*O;
        }
    }
    return determinant;
}
```

Comment: `And BTW I don't know anything about pointers so I literally cannot use them`...what's stopping you from learning them? They are useful. :)

Comment: I have a feeling that you have problem with your input rather than with the calculation...

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh I know but for this particular code I'm not allowed to use them, well the professor said that we can only use the stuff we already know :(.

Comment: @Eugene Input? like how?

Comment: You need to compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), improve the code till you got no warnings and you should **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In function `det()` you have initialised `determinant` only when it was not necessary

```
determinant = 0;
determinant = A[0][0]*A[1][1]-A[0][1]*A[1][0];
```

but when it was needed

```
determinant = determinant + O*(A[0][i]*det(Minor,n-1));
```

there was no previous initialisation. So move

```
determinant = 0;
```

to above `if(n == 2)` near the start of the function.

Answer (score 3):

I made a recursive but efficient and easy algorithm to calculate the determinant of a NxN matrix:

```
int determinantOrderN(int **m, int n)
{
    int i,j,k, factor=1, det=0; int **newm;
    if(m==NULL) return -1;
    if (n==1) return **m; //when matrix is a number, determinant is the number
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        if(NULL == (newm = malloc((n-1) * sizeof(int *)))) return -1;
        for(j=0; j<n-1; j++) if (NULL == (newm[j] = malloc((n-1) * sizeof(int)))) return -1;
        for(j=1; j<n; j++) 
        {
            //skip first row as we dont need it for the adjunt matrixes
            for (k=0; k<n; k++)
            {
                if(k==i) continue; //skip same column
                nuevam[j-1][k<i?k:(k-1)]=m[j][k]; //asign the number to new matrix
            }
        }
        det+= factor*m[0][i]*determinantOrderN(newm, n-1); //recursivity, determinant of the adjunt matrix
        factor*=-1;
        for(j=0;j<orden-1;j++) free(newm[j]);
        free(newm);
    }
    return det;
}
```

Use would be something like:

```
int **matrix, i;
matrix = malloc(3*sizeof(int *));
for(i=0; i<3;i++) matrix[i]=malloc(3*sizeof(int));
//asign all the numbers
printf("%d\n", determinantOrderN(matrix, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C program that calculates the determinant of any MxN matrix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int m,n; // original matrix dimensions

int det(int B[m][n]);

int main() {
    int determinant;
    register int row,column;

    printf("Enter rows and columns\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    
    int A[m][n];

    printf("Enter matrix elements\n");

    for(row = 0; row < m; row++)
        for(column = 0; column < n; column++)
            scanf("%d",&A[row][column]);
            
    determinant = det(A);

    printf("determinant = %d \n",determinant);

    return 0;
}

int det(int B[m][n]) {
    int row_size = m;
    int column_size = n;

    if (row_size != column_size) {
        printf("DimensionError: Operation Not Permitted \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    else if (row_size == 1)
        return (B[0][0]);

    else if (row_size == 2)
        return (B[0][0]*B[1][1] - B[1][0]*B[0][1]);

    else {
        int minor[row_size-1][column_size-1];
        int row_minor, column_minor;
        int firstrow_columnindex;
        int sum = 0;

        register int row,column;

        // exclude first row and current column
        for(firstrow_columnindex = 0; firstrow_columnindex < row_size;
                firstrow_columnindex++) {

            row_minor = 0;

            for(row = 1; row < row_size; row++) {

                column_minor = 0;

                for(column = 0; column < column_size; column++) {
                    if (column == firstrow_columnindex)
                        continue;
                    else
                        minor[row_minor][column_minor] = B[row][column];

                    column_minor++;
                }

                row_minor++;
            }

            m = row_minor;
            n = column_minor;

            if (firstrow_columnindex % 2 == 0)
                sum += B[0][firstrow_columnindex] * det(minor);
            else
                sum -= B[0][firstrow_columnindex] * det(minor);

        }

        return sum;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to other answers, you could also define it this way:

```
int det(int n, int [n][n]);
```

And the implementation would be:

```
int det(int n, int matrix[n][n])
{

}
```

This way, you wouldn't have to go through the hassle of using pointer-to-pointers or dynamically allocating memory. Besides, the function definition works just about anywhere and doesn't require predefined global variables.