# to find the determinant of a user defined matrix using recursion

Tags: c

So i was hoping to make a C program to find the determinant of a "user defined" matrix. the matrix can be of any order (say 2*2 or 3*3 or 4*4.....n*n)
i tried making a simple program to find the determinant of any 2*2 or 3*3 matrix
there are two things i need help with

> correct the logical error in the program because the determinant of 2*2 matrix is wrong.
>   and add recursion to the program so we can find the determinant of an infinite matrix.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int a,b;
        printf("enter the rows and columns of matrix\n");
        scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
        int c[a][b];
        printf("Enter Elements In The Matrix:\n");
        for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
        {
                for(int j=0;j<a;j++)
                {
                        scanf("%d",&c[i][j]);
                }
        }
        printf("\nYour Matrix Is:\n");
        for(int p=0;p<b;p++)
        {
                for(int k=0;k<a;k++)
                {
                        printf("%d\t",c[p][k]);
                }
                printf("\n\n");
        }
        if(a==b)
        {
                printf("\nDeterminent Of Marix Is: ");
                int D1=0,D2=0,D3=0,D;
                for(int n=0;n<a;n++)
                {
                        for(int m=0;m<b;m++)
                        {
                                if(n==0 && m==0)
                                {
                                        D1=c[n][m]*(c[n+1][m+1]*c[n+2][m+2] - c[n+2][m+1]*c[n+1][m+2]);
                                }
                                if(n==0 && m==1)
                                {
                                        D2=c[n][m]*(c[n+1][m-1]*c[n+2][m+1] - c[n+2][m-1]*c[n+1][m+1]);
                                }
                                if(n==0 && m==2)
                                {
                                        D3=c[n][m]*(c[n+1][m-2]*c[n+2][m-1] - c[n+2][m-2]*c[n+1][m-1]);
                                }
                        } 
                }
        D=D1-D2+D3;
        printf("%d\n",D);
        }
 else
        {
                printf("The Matrix Is Not A Square Matric So The 
Determinent Cannot Be Calculated\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: i figured out the logical error for the 2*2 matrix so that part is done. that error is at the part D=D1-D2+D3.

Comment: i tried using recursion but i just can't get the (-/+) signs right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384020/c-program-to-calculate-the-determinant-of-a-nxn-matrix

Comment: also the program is working perfectly fine in case of a 3*3 matrix.

Comment: You do not have a recursive function in your given code. What work have you done towards recursion?

Comment: i only put up the working code. i tried using a recursive program on pen/paper first but i couldn't get it right