# Calculate the determinant of any matrix nxn using function

Tags: c

Guys I want to calculate the determinant of any matrix nxn and I tried this way but it keeps showing me *errors* like:

```
56: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector 
return((tab[0][0] * tab[1][1])-(tab[0][1] * tab[1][0]));*
```

**The code:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define Tmax 100

int determinant (int dim, int tab);

int main(){
    int tab[Tmax][Tmax];
    int dim, i, j;
    int det=0;
    do{
        printf("Enter the dimention of the matrix n x n /n");
        scanf("%d", &dim);
    } while (dim<0 || dim>Tmax);
    for (i=0; i<dim; i++){
        for (j=0; j<dim; j++){
            printf("Enter the element in the %d row and %d column:\n", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d",&tab[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<dim; i++){
        for (j=0; j<dim; j++){
            det = det + determinant(dim, tab[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("%d", det);
    return 0;
}

int determinant (int dim, int tab[][])
    int i, j;
    if (dim==1)
        return tab[0][0];
    else if (dim==2)
        return((tab[0][0] * tab[1][1])-(tab[0][1] * tab[1][0]));
    else
        return (pow(-1 , i+1+j+1) * tab[0][j] * determinant(i+1,tab));
}
```

Is there any thing I can do to this? and also is there any simple way to do it?

*Note: Please no spoils just hints*

Comment: In `determinant`, `tab` is an `int`, not a 2D array.

Comment: C does not allow declarations like `int tab[][]`, you must specify all but the rightmost dimensions.

Comment: Hint: don't use `pow(-1, foo)` it's overkill. Use `(foo % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1`

Comment: This prototype: `int determinant (int dim, int tab);` does not match the function definition: `int determinant (int dim, int tab[][])`

Comment: Initialize all variables before use.  `i` and `j` are of undefined value before use in your code.

Comment: My understanding is that you try to implement the cofactor method. However, it is not exactly what is coded here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems:  This:

```
return (pow(-1 , i+1+j+1) * tab[0][j] * determinant(i+1,tab));
```

Is using `i` & `j` without first being initialized.  change:

```
    int i, j;
```

To:

```
    int i=0, j=0;
```

Regarding:

> `error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector return((tab[0][0] * tab[1][1])-(tab[0][1] * tab[1][0]));*"_`

The following prototype:

```
int determinant (int dim, int tab);
```

does not match the function definition (which is not syntactically correct anyway, `[][]` array formation is not legal C) :

```
int determinant (int dim, int tab[][]){
```

The following is syntactically correct:

```
int determinant (int dim, int tab){//fix argument list to match prototype
    int i=0, j=0;
    if (dim==1)
        return tab;
    else if (dim==2)
        return((tab * tab)-(tab * tab));
    else
        return (pow(-1,i+1+j+1) * tab * determinant(i+1,tab));
}
```

But logically questionable.  Suggest reviewing algorithm of `nxn` determinant and refactoring.

Hint:  a [similar question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41384020/645128) (with viable algorithm.)  See accepted answer for only issue.